# Using wildcard in a batch file with dism function

Tags: powershell, package, wildcard, dism

How would I go about using a wild card for this:

```
dism /online /remove-package /PackageName:Package_for_KB2952664~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.16.0
```

I have tried this:

```
dism /online /remove-package /PackageName:Package_for_KB2952664~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.*.*.*
```

Comment: Parse the included packages.to determined the missing information. Maybe using `Find "2952664"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use wildcards in the `/PackageName` argument. You can retrieve the full list of packages, search the resulting set for the packages you want, then run the remove command for each result.

First, get all the packages:

```
$packages = dism /online /Get-Packages
```

Next, find only the packages that you care about with a regular expression:

```
$matched_packages = $packages | Select-String "Package_for_KB2952664~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~.*$"
```

In the above command, the regex `Package_for_KB2952664~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~.*$` can be changed to a more appropriate regex to search for, if needed.

Next, filter down to just the values from the matches to make it easier to iterate over:

```
$matched_values = $matched_packages | ForEach-Object { $_.Matches[0].Value }
```

Finally, run the `remove-package` command on each match:

```
$matched_values | % {dism /online /remove-package /PackageName:$_}
```

You can make it a one-liner if you prefer:

```
dism /online /Get-Packages | Select-String "Package_for_KB2952664~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~.*$" | ForEach-Object { $_.Matches[0].Value } | % {dism /online /remove-package /PackageName:$_}
```

There may be a simpler way of constructing these commands (my PowerShell is a little rusty) but the above examples will execute the `remove-package` command for each installed version of the package specified in the regex.